# Culling & Scripts

Tags: performance, networking, unity-game-engine, network-programming, culling

I'm no programming expert, and this just came to mind so I figured what better place to ask it. If a GameObject (using Unity here) is culled, but it has a script on it that is set to create particle effects and instantiate objects...and those particle effects and objects are also culled (at the moment) does it still have a cost on performance since the object(s) are culled?

The actual instance that I'm thinking of this for is an online game with a large map. If player B is outside of player A's camera's culling distance, and player B is doing things that create particle effects and objects, player A's local machine will KNOW that player B is doing these things, but it won't actually be drawing (rendering) them...so does player A's machine still put out a high amount of work?

Answer (score 0):

player A's computer will be putting on  a high amount of work. The best way to tell if its going to have an affect on other computers is to test it on LAN with a partner